# Adjust colors of sublots in searbon heatmap (derived from a loop)

Tags: pandas, seaborn, heatmap, subplot

I have a list of different dfs (df_list) containing numbers.
Using a for loop, I create subplots with a heatmap for each df.

```
df_list=[mean, bias, std,  std_diff, trend, rmse]


nrow=2 ; ncol=3 ;


fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(nrows=nrow, ncols=ncol, 
                            figsize=(100,60),
                            gridspec_kw=
                            {'wspace':0.02,
                                'hspace':0.3,
                                })
    
list_ax=ax_array.flatten()

pal1=sns.color_palette('RdBu_r', 15)
pal2=sns.color_palette('gist_heat',15)
    
    
for ax, df in zip(list_ax.flatten(), df_list):
        sns.heatmap(df, cmap=pal1,
                annot=True, 
                fmt='.1f',
                annot_kws={
                'multialignment':'center',
                'size':'small'
                },
                cbar_kws={
                'orientation':'horizontal',
                      },
                  ax=ax)
```

I would like to apply **pal1** for mean, std, trend

and

**pal2** for bias, std_diff and rmse.

Do you have any suggestion on how I can tackle the problem?

*Thanks a lot.*

Comment: I think we can make a list of palette names in a one-to-one relationship to the graph and add them to the loop target.`color_list=['pal1','pal1','pal1','pal2','pal2','pal2'];for ax,df,c in zip(list_ax.flatten(),df_list,color_list):`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't see the wood for the trees, I think. :)